# How to get the real width in IE7 with jquery of elements overflow hidden

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-7

I have a list with 50 elements(not a fixed value)

```
<div style="width:465px;">
    <ul>
     <li>aaa<li>
     <li>aaa<li>
     <li>aaa<li>
     <li>aaa<li>
    ....
     <li>aaa</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

ul has overflow hidden in css....I want to get the width of ul with jquery. I used width() for ul from jquery but in IE7 I get 465, in another modern browser I get a bigger value(i.e. 1549). which is corect. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

In IE7, your width is being returned as a string and is not parsed on IE, i think

try somthing like

```
var w = $("ul").width();
if ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) <= 6) {
    w = parseFloat(w);
}
```

or you could shorten it oo

```
var w = ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) <= 6) ? 
    parseFloat($("ul").width()) : $("ul").width();
```

or really short nd probably really wouldn't hurt too much, :P

```
var w = parseFloat($("ul").width());
```